# Would I use の in this sentence?

Tags: particles

If I wanted to say "My opinion is different from yours" would I say 僕の意見はあなたのと違います?

Answer (score 2):

> 「僕{ぼく}**の**意見{いけん}はあなた**の**と違{ちが}います。」

is simply a perfect sentence in every way.

「あなたの」 here means "***yours***".

> "My opinion is different from yours."

Informally, some native speakers would tend to drop the second 「の」, though.